# applescript with shell script having % "

Tags: shell, applescript

I have a long apple script that does conversion of files, moving files, compression etc.

I have to include a renaming script in-between the script that does rename files e.g. file1.pdf to file0001, file2 to file0002 and so on.

I found the following script works in terminal, but how can I include this in-between my applescript since it has percentage %, quotes " inside of the command.

works in terminal

> rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%04d",$&)/e' ~/Downloads/test/*.pdf

I can't do shell script like this one

> do shell script "rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%04d",$&)/e' " & theFolder & "*.pdf"

this will end up with error since it has percentage %, quotes ".

How can I implement this into my applescript, thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes.

Comment: sorry didn't get you, how to escape quotes and how to place %, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [escape shell arguments in AppleScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827739/escape-shell-arguments-in-applescript)

Comment: My OSX (10.8.4) doesn't have the rename command.  Is this something you have installed with macports/homebrew/fink/(other)?  As such I'm not entirely sure how the 's/\d+/sprintf("%04d",$&)/e' expression should be interpreted in this case.  I assume file1.pdf should be renamed to file0001.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

```
do shell script quoted form of "rename 's/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e' ~/Downloads/test/*.pdf"
```