# escape shell arguments in AppleScript?

Tags: shell, applescript

I have the following command line works well in terminal

> rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%04d",$&)/e' ~/Downloads/test/*.pdf

but I couldn't escape quotes (have single quote and backslash in the script) in applescript, this is what I tried, applescript didn't give me error but I didn't get my files renamed.

```
 set renamer_command to "'s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e'"
 do shell script "/opt/local/bin/rename " & quoted form of renamer_command & " ~/Downloads/test/*.pdf"
```

This is the output I get from Applescript

```
 tell current application
do shell script "/opt/local/bin/rename ''\\''s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e'\\''' ~/Downloads/test/*.pdf"
    --> ""
 end tell
 Result:
""
```

This is gives exactly what I want as seen in the output example.txt

```
 set inString to "'s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e'"
 do shell script "echo " & quoted form of inString & " > ~/Desktop/example.txt"
```

result

```
 's/\d+/sprintf("%04d",$&)/e'
```

Again if I drop the output in my script and just look at the result in applescript then I get backslash in the result

```
 set inString to "'s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e'"
 do shell script "echo " & quoted form of inString
```

result

```
 "'s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e'"
```

I worked around a lot but I couldn't get working script, please suggest me a solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many quotes. Try this:

```
set inString to "s/\\d+/sprintf(\"%04d\",$&)/e"
do shell script "/opt/local/bin/rename " & quoted form of inString & " ~/Downloads/test/*.pdf"
```